# How to shutdown application context between tests

Tags: spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-boot-test

I have 3 groups of tests: unit, integration, acceptance.

- Latter two groups launches ApplicationContext: minimal for "integration" and full for "acceptance".
- Both application contexts register queue subscriber.
- Application contexts are deregistered at the end of entire test run (`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`)

When I run "all tests" 2 different application contexts are started and I have duplicate queue subscribers.

I know following workarounds for this subscribers duplication:

- never run integration and acceptance test together
- use "acceptance" application context for "integration" tests. Downside: test run will take longer time.
- add static registry and manually add/remove listeners. Downside: too complex and easy-to-forget

Are there any convinient way to unload application context after a group of tests?

### UPDATE based on *ndrone* answer

- `@DirtiesContext` is a perfect match
- one more option is to limit cached ApplicationContexts count to one with `spring.test.context.cache.maxSize=1`

### Test superclass example with dirties context

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
    @TestExecutionListeners({FlywayTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
    public abstract class AcceptanceTest {}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `@DirtyContext`? http://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html